# Unicorn downs for few seconds after USR2 and QUIT signals (Should not)

Tags: ruby, capistrano, unicorn

I have a very basic app with unicorn. Rails 5.1 app that simply echos/prints "Hello World". For the tests i gave 4 workers.

unicorn.rb:

```
worker_processes 4
preload_app true

timeout 30
listen '127.0.0.1:3000', :tcp_nopush => true, :backlog => 4096
# Logging
...
```

Now, I send `USR2` signal to master process. Master process successfully received my signal and created another master then marked this as an "*old*" and write PID to an `oldbin` file

Problem starts here. When I make sure second master and their childs created, I send `QUIT` to **old** master. Problem is exactly here. When old master receives `QUIT`, The whole new and old masters and childs dropped and re-created. This makes my system down for few seconds.

Basically, New master kill itself and then re-create. Why? What am I doing wrong here? I thought this is zero downtime. I can assure you I have downtime for 3-5 seconds.

*I checked, old master creates new master with PID 5 (for example) and their childs as 6, 7, 8, 9. When I quit from old one, new master becomes 10 and workers becomes 11,12,13,14. Simply shows that both old and new ones quit and re-**re**-created.*

I do not use `-D` command. I use foreman to generate `systemd` file and this is how it looks like:

```
[Unit]
PartOf=bp-web.target

[Service]
User=Pratha
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/app/releases/20170628140005
Environment=PORT=%i
ExecStart=/bin/bash -lc 'exec bundle exec unicorn -E production -c config/unicorn.rb'
Restart=always
StandardInput=null
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
SyslogIdentifier=%n
KillMode=mixed
TimeoutStopSec=5
```

1. I use capistrano for release-cycle and deployment.
2. If I use puma with threads (even 16 worker 50 threads) i get real "zero downtime".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an expected behavior:

> Supervisord requires the unicorn process to not daemonize. Also sending SIGUSR2 to unicorn causes the old master to die. Since *supervisord watches the old master* **this will cause it to consider the application as exited**, even tho it's running with a new process id. **Finally Supervisor will try to restart the application, and fail to do so because all sockets are in use by the new unicorn master.**

Solution:

1. Either use -D option and start your unicorn rails app yourself without systemd/supervisord. Then USR2 will work.
2. Or use unicornherder for wrapper. This will do the job for you. No downtime.

See link: [Unicorn + Systemd/Supervisord & Zero Downtime = unicornherder](https://weluse.de/blog/zero-downtime-deployments-with-unicorn-and-supervisord.html)